# Why is the argument of complex number determined up to integer multiple of $2 \pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have just started learning about complex number and came across to this **argument of complex number**

Let's say we have a complex number $z$. Then the argument of $z$ can be represented by this: $arg (z) = arctan(y/x)$

[image]

A book I was reading mentioned that

[image]

I can't seem to relate to this concept. Why must the argument of z be represented in integer multiple of $2\pi$?

Comment: That's not what *determined* means here.  Compare: the antiderivative of a function is *determined* up to a constant function. This does not mean the antiderivative is a multiple of a constant function.

Comment: Well, travelling a distance of $\theta$ counterclockwise around the unit circle winds up in the same place as travelling $\theta+2\pi$ around, for instance. So the answer to the question "how far around have we travelled" is only determined up to additions and subtractions of $2\pi$.

Comment: Actually, the $\arctan$ function only maps to angles in the range $(-\pi /2, \pi/ 2)$.  So you might have to add or subtract $\pi$ to get the actual value.  If you want a function which maps to the more useful $(-\pi,\pi)$ range, then you'll need to use the two-argument function $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$.